# Force download in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function download($id,$file_name)
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download( NULL,base_url().'uploads/files/'.$file_name);
}
```

I'm using this function to download a file. The id and file name of the file is passed into the function. But whenever it download that file, it's size becomes very less and also the file does'nt execute.

Things that I've already tried:

- Tried to replace NULL with some random name, the same thing happened
- Replace the file name and file path, the same thing happened
- Tried to pass those values by storing in some variables, same happened

Things I would like to mention:

- The files are stored in localhost I'm using wamp server
- Not original files are being downloaded, means it automatically creates a new file of the same name or the name that I've passed in the function.
- The files are either .exe or .apk which I want to download

What I want to do is that, I want to download same original file or even it is a copy of original then it has to be executable (for .exe)

Comment: Why are you passing NULL to the filename parameter?

Comment: What should I pass then? I've seen this example in Ci manual

Comment: You didn't pay attention, re-read the doc again: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html#force_download

Comment: @MehdiBounya I still didn't get this sir. Can you please rewrite the code?

Comment: Please do not tag-spam!  You cannot be using CodeIgniter version 2 and version 3 simultaneously; and what does `phpMyAdmin` have to do with this?  Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `null` to the `filename` parameter, you need to pass it to the `data` parameter (2nd parameter), so your code should be like this

```
public function download($id,$file_name)
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download(FCPATH.'/uploads/files/'.$file_name, null);
}
```

also, don't concatenate the `base_url()` with the path, you can pass the path to the `base_url('/path/to/file')` function and it'll return the link to that file.

I notice that you are passing the `$id` variable but it's not used, are you using it in another part of the code that is not included?

And why do you even have a function to just call the `force_download()` function? can't you just call it inside the Controller?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The $idwill be used after wards. So for now just checking whether it is downloading or not.

Comment: By the way, the code that you've provided me is redirecting to that URI. passed in force_download() and also an empty page is loading.

Comment: thanks a lot it's working now. Can you please remove that -1 from the question. I'm new to this framework so might ask some silly questions.

Comment: You are welcome, and no actually it's not me who downvoted the question, to avoid downvotes the next time make sure you have searched for the answer, also you can read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okay no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Just do your modification.

```
function download($path, $name)
{
  // make sure it's a file before doing anything!
  if(is_file($path))
  {
    // get the file mime type using the file extension
    $this->load->helper('file');

    $mime = get_mime_by_extension($path);

    // Build the headers to push out the file properly.
    header('Pragma: public');     // required
    header('Expires: 0');         // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($path)).' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);  // Add the mime type from Code igniter.
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');  // Add the file name
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path)); // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile($path); // push it out
    exit();
}
```

Comment: He wants to force, it is just a way.

Comment: Yes but, CodeIgniter already has the Download helper, if you are going to rewrite code, what's the point of using a framework then?